# Change the div color on input focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

What am trying is to change the color of the `div` with letter `s`

```
<div class="search_container">
    <input type="text" class="search_field" placeholder="Search..." />
    <div id="magnify_glass">s</div>
</div>
```

What I tried is this

```
<script>
    $('.search_field').focus(function() {
        $('#magnify_glass').css('color','#ff0000');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your code is in the `<head>` of the document, you just need a document ready handler. Try this:

*Update*

To remove the colour you need to add a `blur` handler too.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.search_field').focus(function() {
            $('#magnify_glass').css('color','#ff0000');
        }).blur(function() {
            $('#magnify_glass').css('color','transparent'); // or whatever the default is.
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, it's better to use a `class` to add styling to an element as it's a better separation of concerns:

```
.focus { color: #F00; }
```

```js
$('.search_field').focus(function() {
    $('#magnify_glass').addClass('focus');
}).blur(function() {
    $('#magnify_glass').removeClass('focus');
});
```

Comment: Just awesome, it works and yes it was in head, can you explain me why it failed? but this leaves the color when the input is unfocused

Comment: You need to add the document ready handler so that your code is executed when the DOM is fully populated. In your original code it would have been trying to assign the `focus` handler to an element which did not yet exist.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, +1, just can you tell me what I need to do to remove the effect if the input is unfocused?

Comment: I always accept, and I'll as soon as the system allows me to :) just for a side note, if we are adding a class to an id, specificity will trouble anyone, so `!important` will come in action here

Answer (score 2):

You code is fine and working you need to ensure you have the code in [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to ensure the element availability before accessed by script and you have jquery library added.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/PVydE/2/)**

```
$('.search_field').focus(function () {
    $('#magnify_glass').css('color', '#ff0000');
}).blur(function() {
    $('#magnify_glass').css('color', '#000000');
})
```

Comment: Thanks, +1, can you tell me how should I remove the red color when the input is unfocused

Comment: You can use blur for unfocus, Update my answer, please have a look.