# CSS: Change parent on focus of child

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, focus

Let's say you have something like:

```
<div class="parent">
    <input class="childInput" type="text" />
    <div class="sibling"></div>
</div>
```

I want to change the appearance of the parent/siblings when the child receives focus. Are there any CSS tricks for doing stuff like this?

---

The reason for my question is as follows:

I'm creating an Angular app which needs editable text fields. It should look like a label until it is clicked, at which point it should look like a normal text input. I styled the text field based on `:focus` to achieve this effect, but the text is cut off by text input's boundaries.

I also used `ng-show`, `ng-hide`, `ng-blur`, `ng-keypress` and `ng-click` to switch between the label and the text input based on blurs, key presses and clicks.

This worked fine except for one thing: After the label's `ng-click="setEdit(this, $event)"` changes the edit boolean used by `ng-show` and `ng-hide` to true, it uses a jQuery call to `.select()` the text input. However, it isn't until after the completion of the `ng-click` that everything is `$digest`'d, so the text input loses focus again.

Since the text input never actually receives focus, using `ng-blur` to revert back to showing the label is buggy: The user has to click in the text input and then click out of it again to revert back to showing the label.

**Edit**:

Here's an example plunk of the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/synSIP?p=preview

Comment: javascript is no option?

Comment: This can't be done using only CSS, you need to use js.

Comment: It is, but I was curious if it can be done with styling. I'll add an edit to get into the reason for my question.

Comment: Parent matching can't be done using CSS only. Siblings matching can be done only if the element is adjacent to the defining element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402514/change-the-div-color-on-input-focus it is the same problem

Answer (score 479, accepted):

You can now do this in pure CSS, so no JavaScript needed

The new CSS pseudo-class `:focus-within` would help for cases like this and will help with accessibility when people use tabbing for navigating, common when using screen readers.

```
.parent:focus-within {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

> The :focus-within pseudo-class matches elements that either themselves
> match :focus or that have descendants which match :focus.

---

## Can I use...

You can check which browsers support this by visiting http://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within

[image]

---

## Demo

```css
fieldset {
  padding: 0 24px 24px !important;
}

fieldset legend {
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
  width: auto;
}

fieldset:focus-within {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

fieldset:focus-within legend {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Parent Element</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: IE should kicked away. R.I.P

Comment: Wow, I did not know about this pseudo-class, this cleaned up my code a lot! Thanks

Comment: This was not possible many years back! What a time to be alive

Answer (score 3):

There is no chance how to do that with CSS. CSS can style only siblings, children, etc. not parents.

You can use simply JS like this:

```
<style>
.parent {background: green}
.focused {background: red;}
</style>
<div class="parent">
    <input class="childInput" type="text" />
    <div class="sibling"></div>
</div>

<script>
$('.parent > *')
    .focus(function() {
        $('.parent').addClass('focused');
    })
    .blur(function() {
        $('.parent').removeClass('focused');
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C4bZ6/

This code takes all direct children of `.parent` and if you focus one of them, class `focused` is added to parent. On blur, this class is removed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added an edit regarding the reason for my question: I wanted to switch between the label and the input on focus/blur, and was having some issues doing this in Angular.

Comment: This is not vanilla JS, this is using jQuery.

Comment: DV - Not JS and OP didn't ask for jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pure CSS to make the text input look like it's not a text input unless it is in focus

http://jsfiddle.net/michaelburtonray/C4bZ6/13/

```
input[type="text"] {
    border-color: transparent;
    transition-duration: 600ms;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline-style: none;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
    border-color: initial;
    cursor: auto;
    transition-duration: 300ms;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried that, but ran into some issues: "...I styled the text field based on :focus to achieve this effect, but the text is cut off by text input's boundaries...". Showing an ellipsis is definitely better than clipping, but I'd like to see the whole thing, if possible. A related question I just asked is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289266/select-input-shown-with-ng-show?noredirect=1#comment37532406_24289266, if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

Try the contenteditible attribute. This may require more work to turn it into usable form data however.

http://jsfiddle.net/michaelburtonray/C4bZ6/20/

```
<span class="parent" contenteditable>Click me</span>
```

Comment: Useful, to be sure. Unfortunately, our client base requires the use of non-HTML5-compliant browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can style it even for `focus-within` and `not(focus-within)` like this (without using JavaScript => more accessible and faster):

```css
.myform:not(:focus-within) button[type="submit"] {
    display: none;
}

.myform:focus-within button[type="submit"] {
    display: block;
}
```