# Select input shown with ng-show

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I'd like to put the focus on an input after it's shown with ng-show. However, this requires a jquery call to be made after the $digest cycle. Does anyone know how to run code after the item is shown, without resorting to setTimeout(), or some such thing?
Here's an example plunk of the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/synSIP?p=preview

Comment: could you be a little more specific please as to what your issue is?

Comment: Sorry. Is that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple directive , dont need jquery :

```
  yourApp.directive('focusme',function(){
   return function(scope,elem,att){
      elem.focus();
   }
  });
```

and You can use it like this :

```
    <input type="text" focusme>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the input to be automatically focused when it is shown use the html5 autofocus attribute:

Comment: That's a good idea. The one problem is that our client base requires the use of non-HTML5-compliant browsers. Also, it only autoselects the first input in the ng-repeat'd list.