# Apply CSS class on hover to other element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've this HTML structure:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li class="item-first">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="description-wrapper">
    <div class="description-first"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So is it possible to set the `.description-first` to `opacity: 1;` when hovering `.item-first`? Or is this just possible with JS? Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is impossible without js. It could have been done using CSS selectors if both were direct brothers in the DOM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make :focus change css of another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807033/make-focus-change-css-of-another-class)

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow You are wrong! Check his code. Completely different HTML structure...

Comment: @Mr.Jo in both cases, the fact is that CSS `:hover` (or `:focus`, like in the other question) cannot cause other elements to change unless those elements are direct siblings or decendents of the target. the answers on the other question describe how to know when it's possible in CSS and also show javascript to accomplish the same effect when it isn't possible in CSS.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Still not disagree!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution. With my solution I can add a class depending on the index.

```js
jQuery("li").hover(function () {
    jQuery(".description-wrapper").children().eq(jQuery(this).index()).toggleClass("description-visible");
});
```

```css
.description-wrapper div {
  opacity: 0;
}

.description-visible {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li class="item-first">First</li>
      <li class="item-second">Second</li>
      <li class="item-third">Third</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="description-wrapper">
    <div class="description-first">First</div>
    <div class="description-second">Second</div>
    <div class="description-third">Third</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Strebler said, this is only possible with Javascript.

```js
function MouseOver(value) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("description-first")[0].setAttribute("style", "opacity: " + value + ";");
}
```

```css
.description-first {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li onmouseover="MouseOver('1');" onmouseout="MouseOver('0');" class="item-first">hover here
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="description-wrapper">
    <div class="description-first">to make this appear</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't modify the <li> because this is generated. So maybe it's possible to make a function on hover that checks if it the 1 hovered element so it add the opacity to the first in the desc wrapper?

Comment: Use `document.getElementsByClassName("class")[0]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. The closest you will get in css is using the `.list-wrapper` on hover like this:

```
.list-wrapper:hover + .description-wrapper > .description-first {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

But that's not what you want I guess. :)