# Change border color of parent div if child input is focused - TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I know TailwindCSS have class `group` to use but that is only use for change styles of child element when the parent element activate some event, but I want it in vise versa.

```html
<div class="parent"> <!-- border color should be red when child is focused -->
  <img class="icon">
  <input class="child" type="text">
</div>
```

And I don't want to re-write css classes. Just use TailwindCSS.

Comment: Look for the [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)  pseudo-class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: Change parent on focus of child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287192/css-change-parent-on-focus-of-child)

Comment: @Plastic Yes, but I wonder if is it already has some tailwind class or need to re-write manually. Thank you btw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [focus-within](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#focus-within) variant

```html
<!-- border will be red when input focuesd -->
<div class="focus-within:border-red-500 border">
  <img class="icon">
  <input class="" type="text">
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/G2RjLuNfeW)

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript for that. I assume your input gets focused by clicking. You can catch the click argument and add a class to the parent.

```
<input class="child" type="text" onclick="focusFunction()">

<script>
function focusFunction() {
    document.getElementByClass("parent").classList.add("focusclass");
}
</script>
```

Everytime you click the Input, your `focusFuncition` is called. This function searches for the `parent` class and adds the `focusclass` to the class attribute. Of course you can change the naming of the classes.

Maybe you have to give your parent an unique id to select it with `getElementByID` instead of class if you use the `parent` class more than once.